# Disable rendering of RGraph attribution

Tags: javascript, rgraph

RGraph.net appends an attribution link back to their site. While it is licensed under CC Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0, attribution can be done in other ways and having the text show up on every single graph can look excessive on some designs. How can it be toggled?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you put the link elsewhere - you can add the data-l="false" attribute to your canvas tag like this:

```
<canvas width="600" height="250" id="cvs" data-l="false">[No canvas]</canvas>
```

Comment: I'm surprised at how quickly this came up - this version was only released earlier today!

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the code in an undocumented and obfuscated section of RGraph.common.core.js, starting at line 4107 in v4.20. If you unminify it, you'll find the magic param that controls the addition of the link is the existence of an attribute, `data-l='false'` on your canvas element.